# How insert data to array that is in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have array of array and i want to add data to inner array in javascript. 
Suppose my code is the following:

```
 self.basketsArray = [];
    self.newCollection = {
        books: []
    };
    self.basketsArray.push(self.newCollection);

  function addNewCollection(){
      self.basketsArray.push(self.newCollection);
  }
  function addDataToArray(index,index2){
     self.basketsArray[index].books.splice(index2, 1, data);
  }
```

In fact, when I want to add data to the inner array it adds to first inner array. What is my problem?

Comment: can you provide fiddle ?

Comment: you problem: you alwasy add same object

Comment: what should do `addDataToArray`? can you provide sample input and sample output for this?

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you pass Objects and Functions by reference, others are just passed by value. You can either directly pass a new object or clone it.

```
// Directly push a new object: 
self.basketsArray.push({books: []}); 

// Clone it, using Angular
self.basketsArray.push(angular.copy({}, self.newCollection);); 

// Clone it, using Lodash
self.basketsArray.push(_.clone(self.newCollection));
```

Be aware that the libraries often propose shallow or deep cloning methods.